# How to return a constant value in select in IBM DB2?

Tags: sql, select, db2

I want to have a constant value in an sql response:

```
SELECT
 'constant_value' AS 'contant_column_name', -- does not work in ibm db2
  real_column1,
  real_column2
FROM real_table
```

This code works in MariaDB/MySQL and MS SQL databases but not in IBM DB2.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT 'constant_value' AS constant_column_name FROM (VALUES (1)) AS T(column_name)`

Comment: This works for this simple example but I need the constant column in a sql statement that gets real data from real table. What must be written after From with the real tables? I edited my question for this purpose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use double-quotes around the new column name, not single quotes, i.e.

```
SELECT
 'constant_value' AS "constant_column_name",
  real_column1,
  real_column2
FROM real_table
```

Works for me on Db2-LUW. If you still get an error, post your Db2-server platform variant and version.

You can also omit the double-quotes, in which case the new column-name must obey identifer rules and will be forced to uppercase.